# Kafka Compacted topic having duplicate messages against same key

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am working on Kafka compacted topic configuration and created a topic with following properties. I understood  that , compaction will not work for active segment, so i have given less values to the segment.bytes and segment.ms properties.

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --create --partitions 3 
--replication-factor 3 --topic test --config "cleanup.policy=compact" --config "delete.retention.ms=1000" 
 --config "segment.ms=1000" --config "min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01" --config "min.compaction.lag.ms=500" --config "segment.bytes = 10737"
```

I have pushed 5 messages to the topic like below.

```
A : {"name":"aaa"}
B : {"name":"bbb"}
C : {"name":"ccc"}
D : {"name":"ddd"}
E : {"name":"eee"}
```

Second time , I have pushed few messages  to the topic like below.

```
A : {"name":"aa1"}
B : {"name":"bb1"}
C : {"name":"cc1"}
```

But i could see the duplicate messages . previous messages are not deleting.

```
A : {"name":"aaa"}
B : {"name":"bbb"}
C : {"name":"ccc"}
D : {"name":"ddd"}
E : {"name":"eee"}
A : {"name":"aa1"}
B : {"name":"bb1"}
C : {"name":"cc1"}
```

Third time ,  i have produced  one more message with key "A"

`A : {"name" : "aa2" }`

Then the first message having key **"A"** and **"aaa"**  value got deleted. But now i am getting last two messages having key "A" and the result of the topic is like below.

```
B : {"name":"bbb"}
C : {"name":"ccc"}
D : {"name":"ddd"}
E : {"name":"eee"}
A : {"name":"aa1"} <--
B : {"name":"bb1"}
C : {"name":"cc1"}
D : {"name":"dd1"}
E : {"name":"ee1"}
A : {"name":"aa2"} <--
```

can any one tell me , what would be the reason  and why the messages are not deleting in second push even though segment.bytes and segment.ms is having less number?
why the topic is having  two messages with same key ?

Thanks!

Comment: Regardless of segment size, how do you know the ratio is allowing the `A` key to be compacted? Have you dumped the individual segments to see where each `A` key exists?

Answer (score 3):

There are many factors when topic compaction is triggered. As you pointed out correctly, the active segment is never compacted. In addition, there is a so-called "dirty ratio" (configurable) that must be reached before a topic is considered for compaction. Furthermore, you can configure how often the compaction thread is actually invoked -- to avoid busy idling, the compaction thread is "pauses" and only invoked from time to time.

Please consult the docs for the corresponding config names.

My general advice is: don't try to reason about compaction. It's complicated and not really reliable. You should always build your application in a way that it can handle duplicate keys.